# Is there any memory leak in this case?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Here is the code, a function that does some buffer operations:

```
void DoProfile (double* profile, double* &projection, int S, int H, double T)
{
    double* p = projection;

    for (int h = 0; h < H; h++)
    {
        memcpy(p, profile, sizeof(double)*S);
        p += S;
    }

    // should p be deleted here like following?
    // delete p;
    // p = NULL;
}
```

I am not sure, but as far as I can think, as long as the point is not newed, then it does not need delete at the end? Someone please educate me. Thanks.

Comment: If you have to ask, it's best to avoid this problem all together: Do not use raw pointers (use references, objects, unique_ptr or shared_ptr instead)

Comment: Care to elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Run [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and check it by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, `p` does not need to be freed at the end of the function call because you are not allocating any memory for it. So this function is OK in that regard.

But of course you need to properly manage the memory for `profile` and `projection` outside this function. You also need to make sure that you have allocated enough memory to hold all of your data so as not to cause access violation errors.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do. Memory size needs carefully calculated before pass to the function. I thought new delete inside function can slow the program, if the function gets called hundreds/thousands of times.

Comment: Like I said, this function is OK. Just be careful what you do in all the other parts of the program you are writing.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `new`, hence no `delete` needed. No leak inside function. Of course we don't know what's happening outside.

BTW, in C++ we tend to avoid raw pointers (using standard containers and smart pointers) and mutating variables via functions arguments (use `return` instead, re-design interface if needed). Also, I don't need any need to pass pointer by reference here (`double* &projection`).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is standard containers or smart pointers runs slower then raw pointers? I mean if the speed is really the concern.

Answer (score 2):

There is no memory leak in the code supplied. No heap allocation therefore no leak.

But you should be careful as to copying using pointers that are not allocated.

My advice is to avoid memcpy. use vectors etc

Comment: I think in this case if projection is well defined outside the function, then I don't see why there is a problem. p is basically pointing to a piece of well formed buffer. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Use the best tools in the workshop to achieve the task. STL prevents you from making mistakes. Yes they run a little slower but so what unless it is a very (i mean very) CPU intensive task such as image rendering. Otherwise use the STL

Answer (score 2):

You may only call `delete` on something returned from `new`. Since `p` is the result of arithmetic (repeated `p += S;`) that advances it past the beginning of a contiguous block, it can't possibly have been returned from `new`. So absolutely not.